# SQL Query to select all under certain age using only date of birth

Tags: sql-server-localdb

How can I select all that are under 20 and female from a SQL database?

The table has a `datetime` for the `dob` and strings for `name`, `surname`, and `sex`. That is the whole table.

I am having trouble calculating the age. I am not even sure this is possible.

I am using SQL Server LocalDB and Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: It would be best if you showed the `CREATE TABLE` statement and sample data.

Comment: If you can calculate your own age, I'm almost sure you will be able to calculate anyone's, given their date of birth and knowing the today's date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is totally possible.

```
SELECT *
FROM <TableName>
WHERE DOB > DATEADD(yy,-20,GETDATE())
  AND Sex = 'F'
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to calculate the age, only the date that is 20 years ago from now.

ANSI SQL query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table_name AS t
WHERE t.sex = 'F'
  AND t.dob > CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '20 YEAR' ;
```